# Get text snippet from search index generated by solr and nutch

Tags: solr, nutch

I have just configured nutch and solr to successfully crawl and index text on a web site, by following the geting started tutorials. Now I am trying to make a search page by modifying the example velocity templates.

Now to my question. How can I tell solr to provide a relevant text snippet of the content of the hits? I only get the following fields associated with each hit:

score, boost, digest, id, segment, title, date, tstamp and url.

The content is really indexed, because I can search for words that I know only is in the fulltext, but I still don't get the fulltext back associated with the hit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

don't forget: indexed is not the same as stored.

You can search words in an document, if all field are indexed, but no field is stored.
To get the content of a specific field, it must be also stored=true in schema.xml

If your fulltext-field is 
stored, so probably the default "field-list-settings" does not include the fulltext-field.
You can add this by using the `fl` parameter:

```
http://<solr-url>:port/select/?......&fl=mytext,*
```

...this example, if your fulltext is stored in the field called mytext

Finally, if you like to have only a snippet of the text with the searched words (not the whole text) look at the highlight-component from solr/lucene

Comment: Perfect. Then I was on the right track. Just did not realized I need to remove the data directory to wipe the index after changing the schema.xml.